# extract image tag from string

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sample :

```
    <p>
        <span class="AM"> *** 
            <img src="image" title="title" style="vertical-align: middle;">***  
        </span> 
        TF1: People needs to learn writting when they are young 
    </p> .

I
```

need to extract the image tag fully(not only the resource attribute) from the string.

expected result :

```
<img src="image" title="title" style="vertical-align: middle;">
```

Comment: What do you mean with extract?

Comment: I mean get the image tag fully from the string ie) with title,style whatever attributes with in the image tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just target the image ?

```
$('.AM img')
```

If you need the outer HTML as a string

```
$('.AM img').get(0).outerHTML
```

and if all that is a string, pass it to jQuery to parse it

```
$(string).find('.AM img');
```

Comment: In my scenario i'd set the string in one variable need to extract the image tag from that. eg : var string = "<p><span class="AM">*** 
<img src="image" title="title" style="vertical-align: middle;">***
</span>TF1: People needs to learn writting when they are young</p> ."; thanks @adeneo

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
var ele = $(theHtmlString);
var imgobj= $('.AM img', ele);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
$('img')[0].outerHTML;
```

Answer (score 0):

//Edit: Thought this is a PHP Question.

In PHP you do it so:

```
$out = null;
preg_match('<img([\w\W]+?)/>', $html, $out);
print_r($out);
```

Comment: time for [**Tony the Pony**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) again

Comment: Sometimes you can match some specific HTML, you don’t have to actually parse it. But `\w\W` is not optimal, since you have to look for a `>`.

Answer (score 0):

Select the element, and match the image tag string:

`document.getElementsByTagName('p').item(0).innerHTML.match(/(<img[^>]+>)/g);`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('span.AM').html();
```

Please try above

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expression to get the image element.
the expression will be

```
/<img[^>]+>/

const match = string.match(/<img[^>]+>/);
const result = match[0];
```